# Positivity of Schur elements in Iwahori-Hecke algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, hecke-algebras

I'm interested in finite Iwahori-Hecke algebras.

If $\mathcal{H}$ is such a Hecke algebra, defined over $\mathbb{Z}[q^{\pm 1/2}]$, and $\Lambda$ an irreductible representation, there is the notion of a *Schur element* $S_\Lambda$. Roughly speaking, to $\Lambda$ you can associate a central element whose matrix in $\Lambda$ is given by $S_\Lambda$ times the identity.

I computed several of these Schur elements in type $A_n$ and I noticed a remarkable positivity property: all the coefficients in $q$ seem to be positive (see below)! I looked up in the literature, but I don't find explicitely this property.

*Is there a concrete reference for this positivity? Does it hold in other types?*

Here a small list of Schur elements:

- For $\mathfrak{sl}_2$:     $1+q$, $1+q^{-1}$
- For $\mathfrak{sl}_3$:     $q+1+q^{-1}$, $1+2q+2q^2+q^3$, $1+2q^{-1}+2q^{-2}+q^{-3}$
- For $\mathfrak{sl}_4$:     $[4]!$ (quantum factorial), $q^2+3q+4+3q^{-1}+q^{-2}$,  $q^{-1}+2+2q+2q^2+q^3$, ...

Comment: How does one compute these? Is there a formula, or similar that you can reference?

Comment: The representation $\Lambda$ is given by a left cell (at least in case $A_n$). Let $(C_w)$ denote the Kazhdan-Lusztig basis and let $(C^w)$ denote its dual basis, such that $tr (C_wC^v) = \delta_w^v$ where you use the standard trace.
Now, for a given left cell $\Lambda$, the element $Z_\Lambda=\sum_{x\in \Lambda}C_xC^x$ is central in $\mathcal{H}$. Its action on $\Lambda$ gives the Schuer element $S_\Lambda$.

There is also a formula, given in Neunhöffers article https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869306001955, Definition 5.1.

Comment: Of course you are no doubt aware of this, but there are many positivity phenomena in Kazhdan-Lusztig theory (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.0791).

Comment: In type A, the Schur element is a q-deformation of the product of the hook lengths. I would then naturally expect the Schur element to be the product of the corresponding quantum integers.

Comment: @PeterMcNamara: This is great! It seems indeed that the Schur elements are the produt of the quantum integers of the hook lengths.
Is there a similar interpretation in other types?

Comment: @AThomas: perhaps using the fake degree polynomials?

Comment: @SamHopkins: What are these (any good reference)? In type $A_n$, do they correspond to hook lengths?

Comment: @AThomas: in Type A they are given by taking the hook length formula $n! \prod_{u\in \lambda}\frac{1}{h(u)}$ and $q$-ifying every term (maybe with a shift by a power of $q$ as well; this is also the $\mathrm{maj}$ generating function of SYT). But there are two different ways to define them abstractly: as Hilbert series of isotypic components of the coinvariant algebra, or degrees of unipotent representations of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338656/fake-degrees-why-coinvariant-algebra-and-classical-groups-over-finite-fields

Answer (score 2):

Together with Maria Chlouveraki, we determined the answer:

The Schur elements are positive in all classical types $A_n, B_n$ and $D_n$ (use the formula of Theorem 4.3. in https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01411063/document, which uses generalized hook lengths). For dihedral groups $I_2(m)$, Theorem 8.3.4. in the book of Geck-Pfeiffer on characters of finite Coxeter groups and Hecke algebras shows that the Schur elements have negative coefficients for $m>4$. For the exceptional cases, by brute force, there are Schur elements with negative coefficients only in type $H_4, F_4$ and $E_8$.

Comment: Did there end up being any connection to fake degrees?